# Scala - sum up each of the members in a list?

Tags: scala

If i have a list of objects (all the same type), can i get some sort of map from this, where each entry in the map corresponds to a member of the type (whether this is set by me or by the system is irrelevant) and the value of each entry is the sum of all the member values in the list?

Eg given an object with members salary, hours and height, and a list of several of these objects, is there some scala code that just gives me back a map with "height" as the sum of the heights, "salary" as the sum of the salaries and "hours" as the sum of the hours?

Sorry, I'm totally new to Scala - I'm just trying to get this working in playframework using Twirl.

Comment: what is so bad about this question that it keeps getting downvoted?

Comment: Add some code that shows what you've got so far

Comment: @Arnon i didn't have any meaningful code - i'm asking how to do it. if i knew how to do it, i wouldn't ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

We'll create a case class Item to represent the class the that has the height, hours, and salary members, and a list of them:

```
case class Item(val height: Int, val hours: Int, val salary: Double)
val items = List(Item(3, 4, 10.0), Item(9, 100, 123.0))
```

Then just initialize a 3-tuple and use foldLeft to accumulate the sum of each member.

```
val sums = items.foldLeft((0, 0, 0.0))((x, item) => 
    (x._1 + item.height, x._2 + item.hours, x._3 + item.salary))
```

We could have accumulated the values into another instance of Item, or into a Map with three members. It doesn't matter. The principle is the same: initialize an object to hold the sums, then foldLeft over the collection.

The nice thing about using a tuple (instead of your requested map) is that you can assign each tuple member to a separate variable:

```
val (sumHeight, sumHurs, sumSalary) = items.foldLeft((0, 0, 0.0))((x, item) => 
    (x._1 + item.height, x._2 + item.hours, x._3 + item.salary))
```

Comment: thanks - i ended up doing this: `@theSums = @{buildings.filter(_._2.getCount() > 0).foldLeft((0, 0, 0, 0))((x, item) => (x._1 + item._1.getHappy, x._2 + item._1.getSupports, x._3 + item._1.getDefenceAdd, x._4 + item._1.getDefenceBonus)) }`

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different solution.
If you just want to sum all items, the Scala collections already provide a 'sum' function to summerize items.
To be able to use that however, you need a Numeric implementation for your case class.

So for the case class Item:

```
case class Item(salary: Double, hours: Int, height: Int)
```

an implicit Numeric[Item] instance can be defined in the Item's companion object:

```
object Item {
  implicit object NumericItem extends Numeric[Item] {
    override def plus(x: Item, y: Item): Item = Item(
      salary = x.salary + y.salary,
      hours  = x.hours  + y.hours,
      height = x.height + y.height
    )

    override def minus(x: Item, y: Item): Item = ???

    override def times(x: Item, y: Item): Item = ???

    override def negate(x: Item): Item = ???

    // Needed to provide starting point for folding using 'sum'
    override def fromInt(x: Int): Item = {
      Item(0,0,0)
    }

    override def toInt(x: Item): Int = ???

    override def toLong(x: Item): Long = ???

    override def toFloat(x: Item): Float = ???

    override def toDouble(x: Item): Double = ???

    override def compare(x: Item, y: Item): Int = ???
  }
}
```

To support the 'sum' function, only the 'plus' and 'fromInt' functions of Numeric have to be implemented.

Now all items in a list

```
val items = List(Item(10.0, 1, 5), Item(5.0, 2, 3), Item(2.5, 3, 8))
items: List[Item] = List(Item(10.0,1,5), Item(5.0,2,3), Item(2.5,3,8))
```

Can be summed using 'sum'

```
val total = items.sum
total: Item = Item(17.5,6,16)
```

Now the totals can just be used a 'total.salary' etc, but if you do want a map, by providing a simple 'toMap' function in Item

```
  def toMap: Map[String, Any] = Map(
    "salary" -> salary,
    "hours"  -> hours,
    "height" -> height
  )
```

the map of totals can be obtained via

```
totals.toMap
res0: Map[String,Any] = Map(salary -> 17.5, hours -> 6, height -> 16)
```